# Using an entry file but leaving it raw

Tags: javascript, webpack

Let's say I have this:

```
entry: {
  polyfills: './polyfills.js',
  vendor: './vendor.js',
  app: './app.js'
}
```

This will output 3 files.

What I want here is to:

- Leave polyfills raw and loaded first.
- Every import done in app that is also done in vendor be moved into vendor.

So I tried with:

```
new CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills'],
  minChunks: Infinity
})
```

That will (in my understanding) say: move common things from `app` to `vendor` and then to `polyfills`. Since polyfills doesn't have anything in common here, `vendor` will have all the common imports with `app`. That covers my first point.

Problem is that `polyfills` will have all the webpack runtime with more things in it and I really need polyfills to be completely raw.

If I do:

```
new CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: ['app', 'vendor'],
  minChunks: Infinity
})
```

I get the vendor thing working too (and with the runtime) but the polyfills will be something like:

```
webpackJsonp([1], [
  // polyfills content
]);
```

So it gets wrapped by webpack and of course when loading I get a red `ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined` which makes sense.

So if I remove this polyfills from entry and I add it manually in a script tag from a cdn or using `CopyWebpackPlugin` it works (or if I manually remove that wrapping). The problem is that I would like webpack to rename the file for cache bust and stuff like that.

So, can I leave polyfills as entry but let webpack ignore about it and not add any wrapper or anything?

Comment: polyfills.js is just one file? it includes other modules ?

Comment: it is a couple of files concatenated in one.